# Mapping View Coordinates To CALayer Coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, calayer

I have a view with a few (nested) layers in them that do custom drawing based upon touches on the owning view.

Given the

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  ....

my view is a delegate of the layer and will receive a callback to draw via

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
  ..

I need to take the points I captured & stored in the touches method and leverage them in the drawing of the layer. However, the coordinates captured in the view need to be transformed to the layer coordinate system before I use them. How does one go about doing this ?

Thanks
Pete